# Client is not getting response from the server

Tags: java, client, chat, server, tcpclient

I am a noob at this . i will be very greatfull if sombody could help me. This is my first port here so i have tried to be as elaborate as possible(If that is the right way to ask questions here).

Ok. Let me explain the problem i am having. I am writing  chat server and a client program. 
The basic thing that i am trying to achieve is to ;
1)connect to the server
2)start sending and receiving messages.

The way i have set up the server is that when ever a client is going to send a messages the server is going to send the msg back to all the connected client.So in other words i am trying to make a chat room

The thing is that my server or client (depending on where the fault is) is giving me three different results under three different condition.

CONDITION ONE: both clients are on the same computer.
RESULT : everything is working the way i expect it to.

CONDITION TWO: One of the clients is on a different computer but still the same local network(my home network)
RESULT: The remote client is able to send messages and the client on the same computer as the server(i'll call it "local client") is able to get them.But the remote client is only getting its own messages back and not getting the messages from the "local client".

CONDITION THREE: One of the clients is remote (somewhere else on the internet).The other is on the same pc as the server.
RESULT: The local client both can send and receive messages but this time the remote client can only send messages , its not getting back any messages neither his own nor from the local client.

[Here is a link to my code . Its not much.](http://coderaid.org/mycode/)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problems are firewall related.

I would suggest you add logging to your Server class and log all received messages where they are coming from and where they are being sent to and log all errors too

Comment: Thank you  for you help. I will try doing that and see if that helps.